# jQuery .load(jQuery(this).attr("id")) vs .load("theID") - how to translate?

Tags: jquery

I have a list (menu). When user clicks on link, I want to load content with ajax. The article to be loaded is to be determined based on the links id attribute.

example:

```
<ul class="ajaxMenu">
    <li><a id="services">Services</a>
    ...
</u>
```

the variables where I store the links to the article, are named the same as the links' id (i.e. Services and the url for the ajax call is stored on var services)

This works:

```
var services = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&tmpl=component";

jQuery(".ajaxMenu > li > a ").click( 
        function(event) { 

            jQuery("#contentComponent").load(services);

        }

    );
```

Since this line of code **jQuery(this).attr("id")** gives me id, I was hoping this would work [it did not work]:

```
var services = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&tmpl=component";
var designs = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&tmpl=component";
var contact = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&tmpl=component";

jQuery(".ajaxMenu > li > a ").click( 
        function(event) { 

            jQuery("#contentComponent").load(jQuery(this).attr("id"));

        }

    );
```

I could create an if, or a loop, iterate through each var, (i.e. if *jQuery(this).attr("id") == "services"...load(services)*)

but I suspect I can achieve this with simple elegant code.

How could I translate jQuery(this).attr("id") into the .load() function without having to if, loop, etc., the value of jQuery(this).attr("id") against the named variables where I stored the urls to be loaded?

Comment: It won't work that way, as attr returns a string "services" not the variable services.

Comment: Please don't do this. You're making your site unnavigable, unsearchable, unbookmarkable; reinventing all the worst features of framesets. To do this properly you need to point your `<a>` links at real documents for accessibility, then augment that with page-content-replacement using hash-navigation, the History API, and hashbang links as backup. Until you have the understanding to do it properly (or a canned script or plugin to do it for you), your content-based documents should leave `load()` well alone and stick with plain, reliable, accessible links.

Comment: @bobince Do you think that a'r answer takes care of the concerns you've raised?

Comment: @Ibero: Using proper links takes care of some but not all accessibility/usability problems. You can now right-click-open-in-new-window/bookmark/middle-click etc, which is a good start. You still get broken back/forward buttons that don't navigate between the pages, and nothing in the address bar to bookmark or link other people to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would firstly put href attributes into your links as it seems like a really good place to put them.

```
<ul class="ajaxMenu">
    <li><a href="...">Services</a>
    ...
</ul>
```

And then in the click handler, do the load call using the href attribute. And don't forget to call `preventDefault` to stop the click from actually reloading the entire page.

```
jQuery(".ajaxMenu > li > a ").click(function(e) { 
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery("#contentComponent").load(href);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: nice idea since (with more work) it would degrade better if the user has JS disabled. Needs to account for the difference between a full page refresh and just dropping a fragment into a particular div.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map from IDs to URLs:

```
var pages = {
    services: "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&tmpl=component",
    designs: "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&tmpl=component",
    contact: "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&tmpl=component"
};
```

and then access that in your `click` handler:

```
jQuery(".ajaxMenu > li > a ").click( 
    function(event) { 
        jQuery("#contentComponent").load(pages[this.id]);
    }
);
```

NB: note also use of `this.id` which is the simpler (and somewhat faster) direct DOM method of reading the clicked element's ID instead of calling `jQuery(this).attr("id")`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first try (that works), you're loading a URL, in the second try, that doesn't, you're just loading an id. Your server is expecting a URL it seems.

Try this:

```
jQuery(".ajaxMenu > li > a ").click( 
        function(event) { 
                        var services = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&tmpl=component";
        var designs = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&tmpl=component";
        var contact = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&tmpl=component";

            var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            if (id == 'services')
            {
                jQuery("#contentComponent").load(services);
            }
            else if (id == 'designs')
            {
                jQuery("#contentComponent").load(designs);
            }
            else if (id == 'contact')
            {
                jQuery("#contentComponent").load(contact);
            }
        }

    );
```

Comment: Your syntax is off, you need to declare those variables either outside of the `click` or within the function.  They can't be there.

Comment: 1.  `switch` is better than `if else if else if else ...`.  2.  this is crying out for a mapping table, not hard coded logic.

Comment: yeah i know, but its another way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because that basically is trying to call `jQuery("#contentComponent").load("Services")` which is not what you want.

If those variables are global you could do this:

```
var url = window[jQuery(this).attr("id")];
jQuery("#contentComponent").load(url);
```

However, using a bunch of global variable is generally frowned upon.  You may want to consider using [jQuery Data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and just store the URL directly on the link.  Or use an object similar to a bunch of other answers that just popped up.